# EXTJS4.1 XTemplate not drawing from Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am trying to create a sidebar navigation for my app with a store loaded with JSON data & XTemplate. There is basic categories & sub categories. However, the Categories are drawing, it isn't creating/rendering the sub-categories in the sidebar. Looking at the docs, mine is almost exactly the same as their "kids" example. What am I doing wrong?

Doc: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

**Model**

```
Ext.define('APP.model.SideBar', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    {name: 'group',     type: 'string'},
    {name: 'tools',     type: 'string', mapping: 'tools'}        
],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : '/js/res/sidebar.json',
    reader: {
         type: 'json',
         root: 'items'
     }
}
});
```

**sidebar.json**

```
{"items": [
{
    "group": "Category1",
    "tools": [
        {"name": "Sub A1"}
    ]
},{
    "group": "Category2",
    "tools": [
       {"name": "Sub B2"},
       {"name": "Sub B3"}
    ]
}]}
```

**View** It draws {group} but not {tools.name}

```
Ext.define('APP.view.SideBar', {
alias: 'widget.appsidebar',
extend: 'Ext.view.View',
id: 'sidebar',
width: 180,
border: false,
cls: 'sidebar-list',

selModel: {
    deselectOnContainerClick: false
},

store: 'SideBar',
itemSelector: '.apptool',
tpl: [
    '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="sidebar-title">{group}</div>',
            '<tpl for="tools">',
                '<div class="apptool">{name}</div>',
            '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'
]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the problem is not in xtemplate but in view. [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View-cfg-itemSelector) for `view.itemSelector` say:

> This is a required setting. A simple CSS selector (e.g. div.some-class
>   or span:first-child) that will be used to determine what nodes this
>   DataView will be working with. The itemSelector is used to map DOM
>   nodes to records. **As such, there should only be one root level element
>   that matches the selector for each record**

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141918/extjs-dataview-itemselector-pointing-to-child-element) concerning the problem of displaying hierarchical data in views.