# Sencha ExtJs view selection mode

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want my Extjs data view to always select at least one record. According to the document I can use mode: 'SINGLE' with allowDeselect: false to achieve this result.

```
                    {
                        itemId: 'data-view',
                        xtype: 'dataview',
                        trackOver: true,
                        overItemCls: 'data-over',
                        selectedItemCls: 'data-selected',
                        mode: 'SINGLE',
                        allowDeselect: false,
                        selModel: {
                            mode: 'SINGLE',
                            allowDeselect: false
                        },
                        itemSelector: me.selector, 
                        tpl: me.tpl
                    },
```

I put `mode` and `allowDeselect` in two places as you can see, but it won't work.

That is, I can still click on any blank space in the data view, and the Selected item will be Deselected.

Can you tell me how to force `allowDeselect` to be false properly?

Comment: check out this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141918/extjs-dataview-itemselector-pointing-to-child-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a bug. As a workaround install this listener:

```
listeners:{
    beforecontainerclick:function() {
        return false;
    }
}
```